# How to upgrade Google Mobile Ads SDK in Xcode when I get this msg: <Google:HTML> You are currently using version 7.6.0 of the SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

When I run my iOS app in the simulator, I get this log message in Xcode:

```
<Google:HTML> You are currently using version 7.6.0 of the SDK. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download. A full list of release notes is available at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes.
```

I downloaded that latest SDK, now how do I update it in my app?

Comment: if you know the English language then in message that you get in xcode from Admob clearly said  ** The latest SDK can be downloaded from http://goo.gl/iGzfsP. A full list of release notes is available at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes.**  then why you not at-least check thouse link and try to download new and replace with old

Comment: @NitinGohel Yea I noticed all I had to do was to drag & drop the new one in the project folder. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you have imported the `GoogleSDK` in your project.

1) If you have used the `.pod` file then you just need to update the pods.

2) If you have imported manually, then just replace the current SDK folder with a new downloaded one.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you, in your previous project version, imported the framework manually - and had chosen 'copy to your files', then a copy of the old framework sits in the Xcode project folder and will be referenced. Delete the old framework both in your Xcode project file and with Finder also the old one in the Xcode project folder.  Then add in Xcode the new framework folder (which will also place a copy in that Xcode project folder).
Clean and re-build.